# Error #1054 - UNKNOWN COLUMN IN FIELD LIST WHILE TRYING TO IMPORT A CSV FILE INTO A DATABASE

Tags: mysql, sql, csv, phpmyadmin

I get an error message:

> 1054 Unknown column 'COL1' in 'field list'

This happens whenever i try to import a csv file directly into a MySQL database using the phpmyAdmin application. I use Wampserver (Apache) on my machine.

I tried to import the same csv file on another computer and it worked just fine, but it gives the error on my computer machine. What could be the problem?

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How are you trying to import -- using the Import tab?

Comment: Yes - i use the import tab in phpMyAdmin to import a csv file into a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, i may have found the answer to MY question: I ran into the same problem today--> The solution is: Select a database to use first and then go on and import the csv file into the chosen database. PhpMyAdmin does not allow direct importation into LOCALHOST and will not tell the error as such rather as some "Unknown column in field-list".
Talk about some PHP Bad error reporting. Thats a first though.

Answer (score 1):

You can in fact import the file using phpMyAdmin. I was also struggling with this issue and just figured it out. In your excel/csv file, the tab name at the bottom of the file (also called 'sheet name') has to be the name of your MYSQL table. Update the sheet name, and retry. It will work.